# document write working on local server but not in pythonanywhere

Tags: python

document write working on local server but not in pythonanywhere

```
   with open(f'templates/{Randomint}.html', 'w') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'templates/3154673393.html'
```

It's a document that dosen't exist but it generates from a python string with

```
 with open(f'templates/{Randomint}.html', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(html_string)
                    webbrowser.open_new_tab(f"http://llonix29.pythonanywhere.com//{Randomint}")
```

and loads with flask

> @app.route(f"/{Randomint}",methods=['GET', 'POST']) def Change():
> return render_template(f'{Randomint}.html',tables=[output.to_html(classes='data')], titles=output.columns.values)

My pythonanywhere route if it helps: [Route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Xuz.png)
,what can i do?

Comment: Does the `templates` directory exist?

Comment: No, it dosent exists, it autogenerates when i click the button "Submit" but for any reason its not generating

Comment: The safest way is to use `os.makedirs('templates', exists_ok=True)` right before trying to write to the directory. Then it'll be created if (and only if) it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is still not working :(          
   os.makedirs('templates', exists_ok=True)
                with open(f'templates/{Randomint}.html', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(html_string)
                    webbrowser.open_new_tab(f"http://llonix29.pythonanywhere.com//{Randomint}")


It dosen't let me crteate the file with that code:

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: 4943295478.html

Comment: Try using the absolute paths, otherwise it might not create those files where you're expecting.